# Clear input ng-model when ng-show is false AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Hi I have a small problem.
I have an input bar which sometimes need to be shown in a form and sometimes not.
I am afraid that if someone put data and then hide it and press send, the data will be sent. So I want to reset the input each time it is hidden.

ng-change isn't a good idea because it doesn't let my write anything.

```
<div class="form-group" ng-show="isItOne=='1' || isItTwo=='2'">
  <label class="col-md-1">someName</label>
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <input class="form-control" type="text" name="someOtherName" ng-model="nameModel" ng-change="clearWhenChanged()">
  </div>
</div>
```

and this is the function

```
$scope.clearWhenChanged = function() {
  $scope.nameModel = "";
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

take out the show condition and use it to control visibility and model value.

```
$scope.showHideField = function(){
    if(isItOne=='1' || isItTwo=='2'){
        return true;
    }
    $scope.nameModel= "";
}
```

call it in your div:
`<div class="form-group" ng-show="showHideField()">`

this also provides the flexibility to pass a flag based on which you can decide whether to clear the field's value or not .. :)

Answer (score 0):

You could call a function instead where you set the `isItOne` variable. In that function you could set the variable to `1` or `2` *and* clear the model value.

**HTML**

```
<div class="form-group" ng-show="show()">
    <label class="col-md-1">someName</label>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <input class="form-control" type="text" name="someOtherName" ng-model="nameModel" ng-change="clearWhenChanged()">
    </div>
</div>
```

**Controller**

```
$scope.show = function() {
    if ($scope.isItOne == '1' || $scope.isItOne == '2');
        return true;
    $scope.nameModel = '';
}
```

Having said all that it might be a better option to just simply *unset* the model's value on submit in cases when you don't want it to be sent.

Answer (score -2):

use the tag attribute `ng-if="your condition"`, This will render the tag only when the condition is true. Otherwise it will remove the whole input from DOM.